# Busybox awk: How to treat each character in String as integer to perform bitwise operations?

Tags: awk, openwrt, busybox

I wanna change [SSID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_set_%28802.11_network%29#Service_set_identification_.28SSID.29) wifi network name dynamically in [OpenWRT](http://openwrt.org) via script which grab information from internet.

Because the information grabbed from internet may contains multiple-bytes characters, so it's can be easily truncated to invalid UTF-8 bytes sequence, so I want to use awk (busybox) to fix it. However, when I try to use bitwise function `and` on a String and integer, the result always return `0`.

```
awk 'BEGIN{v="a"; print and(v,0xC0)}'
```

How to treat character in String as integer in awk like we can do in C/C++?  `char p[]="abc"; printf ("%d",*(p+1) & 0xC0);`

Comment: @EdMorton I am confused. I can do this `awk 'BEGIN{c=7;print and(c,3)}'` and get `3` and this `awk 'BEGIN{c=7;print and(c,15)}'` and get `7`. And `and` is listed here... https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Bitwise-Functions.html

Comment: @MarkSetchell yeah you're right, I've never come across it and didn't bother to check. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, when c is an integer, it works fine. but if c is a character/string, it will always returns 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your own `ord` function like this - heavily borrowed from GNU Awk User's Guide - [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Ordinal-Functions.html)

```
#!/bin/bash

awk '
BEGIN    {  _ord_init() 
            printf("ord(a) = %d\n", ord("a"))
         }

function _ord_init(    low, high, i, t)
{
    low = sprintf("%c", 7) # BEL is ascii 7
    if (low == "\a") {    # regular ascii
        low = 0
        high = 127
    } else if (sprintf("%c", 128 + 7) == "\a") {
        # ascii, mark parity
        low = 128
        high = 255
    } else {        # ebcdic(!)
        low = 0
        high = 255
    }

    for (i = low; i <= high; i++) {
        t = sprintf("%c", i)
        _ord_[t] = i
    }
}

function ord(str,c)
{
    # only first character is of interest
    c = substr(str, 1, 1)
    return _ord_[c]
}'
```

**Output**

```
ord(a) = 97
```

Comment: Thanks! This works with busybox awk.  I've simplified the ord function (deal all 0-255 characters) and applied in my code: https://github.com/moontide/Dynamic-SSID-for-OpenWRT/blob/master/cnbeta-mobile-news.sh

Comment: Excellent - glad to be of assistance. Nice idea to share your code :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don;t know if it's what you mean since you didn't provide sample input and expected output but take a look at this with GNU awk and maybe it'll help:

```
$ gawk -lordchr 'BEGIN{v="a"; print v " -> " ord(v) " -> " chr(ord(v))}'
a -> 97 -> a
```

Comment: thanks for the gawk example, the behavior act as expected, but unfortunately, i can't install gawk in my [TP-Link WR841N wireless router](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/tl-wr841nd) which only have 4M flash totally (less than 1M is available), and the gawk version in OpenWRT doesn't have `-l` option.

Comment: @LiuYan刘研 I don't know your OpenWRT environment, but `perl` also has `ord` and `char`...